# Careers, translation error

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

When going to http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ using a French IP address, a green message pops up saying

> Vous visitez de la France? Jetez un coup d'oeil sur la version Careers 2.0 France

(approximate translation : you're visiting France ? Take a look on Careers 2.0 France)

`Vous visitez de la France?` doesn't make much sense in french, it should be something like `Vous êtes en France ?` which means "You're in France ?".

Comment: Doesn’t it really mean “you’re visiting *from* France?”, which makes some sense while not sounding completely natural? (French is not my first language so I could be totally wrong, though.)

Comment: @minitech when debating language translation, I am usually going to favor the native speaker :-)  Besides, Google translate, which is **always** perfect, favors the OP's translation.

Comment: Thanks Andre.  We'll run this by our translators.

Comment: @psubsee2003: I suppose the interpretation that’s awkward is “you’re visiting some France?”

Comment: If you drop "de", you get "You're visiting France?". If you replace "de" with "depuis", you do get "You're visiting from France?". But "visiter" doesn't really work if what was meant was "Browsing from France?". If you keep the "de" as is, then yes that doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I don't like either of the above. Why not `Vous êtes francophone?` or `Vous êtes un(e) internaute francophone?` Please note that Belgians (Wallonie) and e. g. people from Lausanne, Switzerland speak perfect French and would prefer not to be called "French". Hence by mentioning "France" directly in the headline, you would automatically limit the French-speaking Careers 2.0 to France *only*, which might not be your original intention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text has now been updated, so when visiting from France you will now see "Vous êtes en France?..."